# Write a program that writes 100 random integers created randomly into a file. Python File i/o

Tags: python, file, random, io, integer

```
import random

afile = open("Random_intger.txt", "w")
for i in range(input("The 100 random integers written are: ")):
    line = str(random.randint(1,100))
    afile.write(line)
    print(line)
afile.close()

print("\nReading the file now." )
afile = open("Random_integer.txt", "r")
print(afile.read())
afile.close()
```

When I run it:

- It says `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
- It creates the file labeled `Random_intger.txt` but there are no integers.
- also, I'm using a MacBook Air, is that part of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make the below changes in your code.

```
for i in range(**int(input("The 100 random integers written are: "))**):
```

you need to convert the data from stdin to integer, the default type from the input function is a string.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code. The first one is that random.randint(1,100) is not giving you 100 random numbers but a single random value between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive) and that your for loop is a bit buggy (don't use input here, or do you want to read something from stdin?).

Next thing: You are opening the file "Random_intger.txt" to write your numbers to. But you read from the file "Random_int***e***ger.txt" ...

Fixed code:

```
import random

filename = "Random_integer.txt"

# use a with statement. Like this you don't need to
# remember to close the stream ...
with open(filename, "w") as afile:
    print("The 100 random integers written are: ")
    for i in range(100):
        line = str(random.randint(1,100))
        afile.write(line)
        afile.write("\n")
        print(line)

print("\nReading the file now." )
with open(filename, "r") as afile:
    print(afile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
out_file = "Random_integer.txt"
afile = open(out_file, "w")
for i in range(100):
    line = str(random.randint(1,100)) + '\n'
    afile.write(line)
    print(line)

afile.close()

print("Reading the file now." )
afile = open(out_file, "r")
print(afile.read())
afile.close()
```